# Own export-to-file function in pythonOCC

Tags: python, autocad, cad, opencascade, pythonocc

I am new to pythonOCC and opencascade. I am tasked with writing a custom function that saves a created object to a file. I can't find any information on this topic in both pythonOCC itself and opencascade. Could someone please send some material or explain or share a piece of code in any language on how to make such a save so that the object can be loaded and displayed later? Thank you very much in advance!

I managed to write a function that records the coordinates of the vertices for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.